# What is the scope of pr_cont in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I read about `pr_cont()` in the documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/printk-basics.html#c.pr_cont) but still not clear. The documentation says that it :

> Continues a previous log message in the same line.

As expected, for the below code I get the following output.

```
void another_func(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "This is another function\n");
    pr_cont(KERN_INFO "Testing\n");
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
[  830.463883] This is another function
[  830.463903] Testing
```

But what is the scope of "previous message" here ? Will it append to any dmesg log preceding it, no matter where that previous dmesg came from?

Answer (score 1):

This usage is incorrect:

```c
void another_func(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "This is another function\n");
    pr_cont(KERN_INFO "Testing\n");
}
```

`pr_cont(KERN_INFO "Testing\n");` should be `pr_cont("Testing\n");` and is equivalent to `printk(KERN_CONT "Testing\n");`.

The `KERN_CONT` tag only continues the previous log message if the previous log message does not end with a newline (`'\n'`). Otherwise it begins a new log message with the `KERN_DEFAULT` log level.

Here is an example of correct usage:

```c
void another_func(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "This is another function... ");
    pr_cont("Testing\n"); /* or: printk(KERN_CONT "Testing\n"); */
}
```

Normally, the two function calls will produce a single log message with at the INFO log-level: `This is another function... Testing`. However, if another `printk` call (without `KERN_CONT`) manages to sneak inbetween, the first log message will be finalized with a newline.

This `another_func()`:

```c
void sneaky(void);

void another_func(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "First message... ");
    sneaky();  /* Could be called during preemption for example. */
    printk(KERN_CONT "Continued first\n");
}

void sneaky(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Sneaky\n");
}
```

produces these three messages:

```
First message ... 
Sneaky
Continued first
```

Even sneakier, this `another_func()`:

```c
void sneakier(void);

void another_func(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "First message... ");
    sneakier();  /* Could be called during preemption for example. */
    printk(KERN_CONT "Continued first\n");
}

void sneakier(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Sneaky ... ");
}
```

produces these two messages with the wrong message continued:

```
First message ... 
Sneaky ... Continued first
```

Comment: Can you enable syntax highlighting in your answer?

Comment: @0andriy Done the syntax highlighting.